# Run Bukkit server on boot

Tags: boot, minecraft

This may seem a bit Pointless, but i am new to scripting in Linux.
I would like to know how I would Run a Shell Script* to run on boot and allow me to remote desktop it at any time. I am planning to use it as a Minecraft Server So any Help Would be appreciated.
Emersont1 :)
the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh  
 BINDIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")  
 cd "$BINDIR"  
 java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remember RPi **has very slow performance** for Minecraft server - **IF** it will work after all it won't be able to handle more than few players.
2. **Startup script**
   It is very easy - just put your startup script into /etc/init.d folder and make the file executable (`chmod +x /etc/init.d/filename`)
3. You need it to run in 'screen', which will hold the server on.

Install the program called screen: `aptitude install screen`

and your final startup script **could look** like this (you can not allocate 1024MB of RAM, because RPi has only 512):

```
#!/bin/sh  
 screen java -Xmx450M -jar /path/to/file/craftbukkit.jar -o true
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i only intend to use it between me and a few freinds but is it possible to make it faster by having memory swap space

Comment: also will i need to log on to the user if so, how do i bypass it?